# Creating record pairs n PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a PySpark DataFrame that looks like:

```
+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+
|  A|  1|  2|
|  B|  3|  4|
|  C|  5|  6|
|  D|  7|  8|
+---+---+---+
```

I want a resultant DataFrame that contains pairs of record (every record against every other except itself) present in the above DataFrame. There shouldn't be duplicate pairs. For example if A-B and B-A occurs, only A-B is retained.

No. of pairs should be equal to len(df) * (len(df) - 1) / 2 (= 6 for above DataFrame)

Expected output:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|x_1|y_1|z_1|x_2|y_2|z_2|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  1|  2|  B|  3|  4|
|  A|  1|  2|  C|  5|  6|
|  A|  1|  2|  D|  7|  8|
|  B|  3|  4|  C|  5|  6|
|  B|  3|  4|  D|  7|  8|
|  C|  5|  6|  D|  7|  8|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

How do I do this in PySpark? Is there any join like self join or cartesian product that does it? Thanks.

-- EDIT --

I was able to do a cross join and get all pairs (16 pairs).

```
temp2 = temp.withColumnRenamed('x', 'x_1').crossJoin(temp.withColumnRenamed('x', 'x_2'))
temp2.orderBy(['x_1', 'x_2'], ascending = [True, True]).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|x_1|  y|  z|x_2|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  1|  2|  A|  1|  2|
|  A|  1|  2|  B|  3|  4|
|  A|  1|  2|  C|  5|  6|
|  A|  1|  2|  D|  7|  8|
|  B|  3|  4|  A|  1|  2|
|  B|  3|  4|  B|  3|  4|
|  B|  3|  4|  C|  5|  6|
|  B|  3|  4|  D|  7|  8|
|  C|  5|  6|  A|  1|  2|
|  C|  5|  6|  B|  3|  4|
|  C|  5|  6|  C|  5|  6|
|  C|  5|  6|  D|  7|  8|
|  D|  7|  8|  A|  1|  2|
|  D|  7|  8|  B|  3|  4|
|  D|  7|  8|  C|  5|  6|
|  D|  7|  8|  D|  7|  8|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

But I do not want redundant and self pairs.

Answer (score 1):

this task requieres a non equi-join which is terrible in terms of performances. 
I hope you do not have too many lines.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as w

a = [
    ("A", 1,2),
    ("B", 3,4),
    ("C", 5,6),
    ("D", 7,8),
]

b = "x y z".split()

df = spark.createDataFrame(a,b)


df_2 = df.withColumn(
    "nb", 
    F.row_number().over(w.orderBy("x"))
)


df_final = df_2.alias("df_l").crossJoin(df_2.alias("df_r"))

df_final.where("df_l.nb < df_r.nb").select(
    "df_l.x",
    "df_l.y",
    "df_l.z",
    "df_r.x",
    "df_r.y",
    "df_r.z",
).show()

+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  z|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  1|  2|  B|  3|  4|
|  A|  1|  2|  C|  5|  6|
|  A|  1|  2|  D|  7|  8|
|  B|  3|  4|  C|  5|  6|
|  B|  3|  4|  D|  7|  8|
|  C|  5|  6|  D|  7|  8|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Yes I have records in millions.